# Profiling disk access

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, profiling, disk

Currently I am working on a MFC application which reads and writes in to the disk. Sometimes this application runs amazingly fast and sometimes it is damn slow. I am guessing that it is because of the disk access involved, hence I want to profile it. These are some questions in this regard:

(1).Currently I am using [AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/) profiler to profile the application. Has anybody tried profiling disk access using this? or is there any other tool available which I can use?

(2). What are the most important disk parameters I should be looking at?

(3). If I have multiple threads trying to read and write the data from disk does it affect the performance? i.e. am I better off having a single threaded access to the disk?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Windows Performance Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305187(loband).aspx) for this.  You can enable trace providers for disk I/O events and see the I/O time and disk service time for each.  It does have a bit of a learning curve though.  This will also let you determine which file I/O's actually result in real-access to the disk and aren't handled by the cache manager.

Most important parameters are disk service time and queue length.  Disk service time is how long the disk actually took to service the request.  Queue length indicates if your disk request is backed up behind other requests.

For many threads w/ reads & writes - Many disks have poor performance in the face of reads with background writes.  If you have various threads doing lots of disk I/O to random locations on the disk, you may wind up starving certain requests.

Answer (score 1):

To help you with (2):

1. Try to batch up your writes to disk to avoid many small calls to write. When you're done flushing your buffer, call commit. commit (aka fsync) is an expensive operation, so becomes even more so when there are lots of small writes.
2. On windows file handles you can experiment with  [FILE FLAG WRITE THROUGH](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99794)  to increase write speeds. Supposedly commit doesn't have to be called with handles using this flag.
3. If data you are writing to disk will also be accessed through reading, consider writing to an in memory structure first, having another thread read from the structure to write it to disk. This will help avoid calls to read data from disk that you have just written.

Hopefully this helps....

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is, if you can't pause all threads at the same time and examine their state, focus on one of them and pause that, while it's being "damn slow". [This is a little known but effective technique.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)

Since it is being extremely slow compared to what it could be, whatever it is waiting for it is waiting for probably 99% of the time, so when you pause it you will see it. That's true whether it's one big wait, or a zillion little ones. Look at the whole call stack. The culprit may be somewhere in the middle of the stack.

If you're not sure, pause it two or three times. The culprit will be on all stack samples.