# What does "Disk Profiling" mean (related to hard disks)?

Tags: profiling, scheduling, disk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Profiling disk access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773982/profiling-disk-access)

Thanks for stopping by.

I am doing a project on disk scheduling. I have encountered the word "Disk Profiling" many times but I am not able to find out what actually it means. I could just get the vague idea that it has something related to simulation...so please guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773982](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773982/profiling-disk-access)

Comment: Thank you...but it was not clear to me in the beginning...later i was able to understand that Disk profiling means (not formally) estimating various parameters (of our disk) which are required in our problem domain...and many tools are available to do that job.Please correct me if i am in any way misleading or totally wrong.